# Failed EC2 launching in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to replicate this lab :https://github.com/aws-samples/ec2-spot-montecarlo-workshop, But keep getting an error `The provided credentials do not have permission to create the service-linked role for EC2 Spot Instances.` seems like when it tries to create instance it fails, does anyone have an idea why ? I made sure to give it all permission role but didn't work ...

Comment: Try with the root account first. If it works, let's look St the IAM role again.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by root account please?  @AvivLo

Comment: The root account means the account with all privileges. IAM roles are like subusers with limited privilege.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that credentials which you use (IAM user or role) do not have permissions to execute an action [iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_CreateServiceLinkedRole.html). The action:

> Grants permission to create an IAM role that allows an AWS service to perform actions on your behalf

Please double check the IAM user and credentials which you use.

Comment: I've create a role with all with all access so can't see where I went wrong, can you show me what the role I need to use might look like  ?

Comment: Do you use Admin credentials to do the tutorial?  Can you launch instances in console? Do you use Admin credentials. Maybe if you update your questions will the relevant info, it will be easier to provide better answer.

Answer (score 0):

When lodging a spot request – there is a service-linked role that needs to be created (if it does not exist) in **IAM** called **AWSServiceRoleForEC2Spot**.

Check that the IAM user has the permission:

*iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole*

More in the docs:  
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html#service-linked-roles-spot-instance-requests